# What is wrong with the below tsql code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * FROM AnySchema.AnyTable
WHERE AnyColumn = SomeCondition

COMMIT
```

I know the transaction is not required here because it is just a select but just want to know how bad a programming it is and whether it is going to be an overhead on the DB engine.

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43254/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-always-create-a-transaction

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way - ask yourself what a transaction will give you, not what it will cost you. We use transactions to accomplish goals, not just for fun :) In any case, everything is always in *some* transaction (on MS SQL, usually an auto-commit transaction), so there's little point if using transactions the way you do - that's already provided "for free" by the server.

Answer (score 2):

You may use transaction on `SELECT` statements to ensure nobody else could update / delete records of the table of while the bunch of your select queries are executing.

**Using** **WITH(NOLOCK)**:

Anyways, you may also use ***`WITH(NOLOCK)`*** for t_sql

***`SELECT * FROM AnySchema.AnyTable WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE AnyColumn = SomeCondition`***

***`WITH (NOLOCK)`*** is the equivalent of using *READ UNCOMMITED* as a transaction isolation level. Here stand the risk of reading an uncommitted row that is subsequently rolled back, i.e. data that never made it into the database.
So, while it can prevent reads being deadlocked by other operations, it comes with a risk.

**TRANSACTION**  **Block :**

Using `TRANSACTION` block will not cause ***much of*** extra DB overload but if you keep the same type practice on, and suppose , at any SQL block you forget (you / your developers may forget, right ?) to close the transaction, then other processes can't work on the same table.

Anyways, ***it depends on what type of application you are using***. If very frequent `update` and `select` things are there , it is advised not to use such transaction blocks. If medium level of updates and select are there, occurs next to each other, you may use transaction blocks for `select` (but ensure to close the transaction).

Comment: `WITH (NOLOCK)` comes with many more risks than just reading an uncommitted rows. And there's no saying if the transaction blocks the whole table, or just a few rows, or a section of an index.

Comment: More explicitly, you could read the same row twice, or not at all, when using NOLOCK or READ UNCOMMITTED (same thing).

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a good question. To understand what's going on, you need to know about `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`.

> When ON, the system is in implicit transaction mode. This means that if @@TRANCOUNT = 0, any of the following Transact-SQL statements begins a new transaction. It is equivalent to an unseen BEGIN TRANSACTION being executed first:
>
> When OFF, each of the preceding T-SQL statements is bounded by an unseen BEGIN TRANSACTION and an unseen COMMIT TRANSACTION statement. When OFF, we say the transaction mode is autocommit. **[this is the default]**
>
> If your T-SQL code visibly issues a BEGIN TRANSACTION, we say the transaction mode is explicit.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx

Since the SQL Server would have created a transaction for you, manually doing doesn't actually change anything. The exact same thing would have happened either way.

---

Summary: What you are doing isn't 'wrong' because it has no effect, but unnecessary and confusing to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be taking a holdlock and most likely a tablock
[table hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

That is not always a good thing as you would block any update or deletes (maybe even inserts)

It would be better to let SQL decide what level of of locks to take.  Most likely pagelocks.  I would stay away from nolock as bad stuff can happen.

On a select on a single table just let the optimizer do it's thing.